# How can I survive the dark tower in Tower of the Sorcerer?

Tags: tower-of-the-sorcerer

I've managed to finish the first part of the [Tower of the Sorcerer](http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/tower-of-the-sorcerer) game more than once, but each time I am ridiculously underpowered when entering the 2nd, "dark" tower. Sometimes even the first monster kills me, but even on my best try I was stopped in a pretty early level by unbeatable (for me) monsters.

My question is, how can I be strong enough when finishing the first tower for taking on the 2nd one? I realize the game is actually a large logic puzzle, not really an RPG, and I'm guessing there must be some route which solves this problem.

Comment: The downloads don`t seem to work for me (Vista possibly), do you have links for any other versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don`t have a download of the game but here are some links to part of a playthrough:

Part 1:

Part 2:

Other parts are listed in links on YouTube. Watching those should give you some good advice.

Comment: It's pretty tedious watching through this all, but he does choose a route which seems to lead to success.

Comment: Thanks for checking back Oak. The strategy isn't clear but at least you have a route that gets you further now.